# SDL OpenGL window instantly closes

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

so i have just started playing with sdl and i have it working fine in a single class but for some reason when i separate things into seperate classes the display opens a insta closes. an ideas ?

Main Class Header

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>
#include <glew.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "Input.h"
#include "Display.h"
#include "RenderingEngine.h"
#include "PhysicsEngine.h"

class Main
{   
public:
    Main();
    ~Main();

    /* Engine settings & Engine Controlls*/
    void start();
    void stop();
    void pause(bool value);
    void run();

private:

    /* Loop Controllers */
    bool running;
    bool paused;


    /* Engine Initialisation */
    void initSDL();

    RenderingEngine render_core  = RenderingEngine(4, 2);
    PhysicsEngine   physics_core = PhysicsEngine();
    Display     display      = Display("game engine", 900, 900, 900, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    Input input;


};
```

Main Class

```
#include "Main.h"

Main::Main()
{
   initSDL();
   start();
}


Main::~Main()
{

}

void Main::initSDL()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
}

void Main::start()
{
    if (running) return;
        running = true;
        run();
}

void Main::stop()
{
if (!running) return;
     running = false;
     exit(0);
}   

void Main::pause(bool value)
{
    paused = value;
}

void Main::run()
{

  while (running)
  {

     if (!paused)
     {

     }
    render_core.render();
    display.swapBackBuffer();
    input.update();
   }
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

  Main engine;

  return 0;
}
```

Display Header

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

class Display
{   
public:
    Display(const char* name, int x, int y, int w, int h, Uint32 flags);
    ~Display();

    void swapBackBuffer();

private:

    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    int h;

    const char* name;

    Uint32 flags;
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_GLContext opengl;

};
```

Display Class

```
#include "Display.h"

Display::Display(const char* n, int x, int y, int w, int h, Uint32 f)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->w = w;
    this->h = h;
    this->name = name;
    this->flags = flags;

    this->window = SDL_CreateWindow(n, x, y, w, h, f);
    this->opengl = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, opengl);
    printf("Display: initialised\n\n");
}


Display::~Display()
{
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(opengl);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    printf("Display: destroyed\n\n");
}

void Display::swapBackBuffer()
{
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}
```

Render Engine class.... there isn't anything important in the header

```
#include "RenderingEngine.h"


RenderingEngine::RenderingEngine(int major_version, int minor_version)
{
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, major_version);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, minor_version);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 32);
    setClearColour(0, 0, 0, 1);
    printf("Rendering Engine:: initialised\n\n");
}


RenderingEngine::~RenderingEngine()
{
    printf("Rendering Engine:: destroyed\n");
}

void RenderingEngine::setClearColour(float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    glClearColor(r, g, b, a);
}

void RenderingEngine::clearScreen()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT || GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void RenderingEngine::render()
{
    clearScreen();
}
```

input class

```
   #include "Input.h"

Input::Input()
{
    printf("Input:: initialised\n");
}


Input::~Input()
{
    printf("Input:: destroyed\n");
}

void Input::setMouseVisabilityTo(bool value)
{
    if (value) SDL_ShowCursor(1);
    else       SDL_ShowCursor(0);
}

int Input::getMouseX()
{
    return mouseX;
}

int Input::getMouseY()
{
    return mouseY;
}

void Input::update()
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {

        case SDL_QUIT:

            break;

        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            keyboard[event.key.keysym.sym] = true;
            break;

        case SDL_KEYUP:
            keyboard[event.key.keysym.sym] = false;
            break;

        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse[event.button.button] = true;
            break;

        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mouse[event.button.button] = false;
            break;

        case SDL_MOUSEWHEEL:

            break;

        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            mouseX = event.button.x;
            mouseY = event.button.y;
            break;
        }   
    }   
}
```

i know there are a lot a files so the help will be greatly appreciated, this has been bugging me for a while now

my edited main.h file

```
#include "Display.h"
#include "RenderingEngine.h"
#include "PhysicsEngine.h"

class Main
{
public:
    Main() :
        render_core(4, 2),
        display("game engine", 900, 900, 900, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL),
        physics_core(),
        input()
    {
        running = false;
        paused = false;
        initSDL();
        start();
    }


    ~Main();

    /* Engine settings & Engine Controlls*/
    void start();
    void stop();
    void pause(bool value);
    void run();

private:

    /* Loop Controllers */
    bool running;
    bool paused;


    /* Engine Initialisation */
    void initSDL();

    RenderingEngine render_core;
    PhysicsEngine   physics_core;
    Display     display;

    Input input;
```

Comment: Do you ever set `running` to `false`? You should always initialize your variables in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this some weird version of C++ (*e.g.* C++11) where you can declare and initialize a non-static member variable all in the same statement?

You should not be doing that kind of thing, the order in which your render context is constructed and initialized in relation to the rest of your software is extremely important. *This is what constructors are for.*

Assuming you actually are intentionally (*ab*)using C++11 here, your window closes immediately because this statement:

```cpp
Display     display = Display("game engine", 900, 900, 900, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
```

Constructs a `Display` object, and then makes a copy of that object and assigns it to `display`. After this statement "returns", the original object is destroyed.

And look at what the destructor for `Display` does:

```cpp
Display::~Display()
{
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(opengl);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    printf("Display: destroyed\n\n");
}
```

Long story short, do not initialize your members this way. Constructors were perfectly fine before C++11 came along and made life more difficult.

Consider something like the following ***constructor*** instead:

```cpp
Main () : render_core  (4, 2),
          display      ("game engine", 900, 900, 900, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL),
          physics_core ()
{
  initSDL ();
  start   ();
}

...

private:
  RenderingEngine render_core;
  PhysicsEngine   physics_core;
  Display         display;
```

This solution initializes all of the members of `Main` when it is constructed, without any copy-assignment and is compatible with a much wider range of C++ compilers. No temporary `Display` object in this code means that your window is not going to be created and then immediately destroyed.

Comment: hi thanks for the insight on that but after adding that constructor and changing my running and paused bools to be initialized it still just instantly disperses :/

Comment: You changed the declaration of `Display display`, right?

Comment: yeah, i will edit my question to show you what i have changed

Comment: @DanielCollier: That should have taken care of the problem, now I have to wonder how your `Main` object is created? Can you show a few lines of code around the point where you construct your `Main` object?

Comment: it's in the second code block that i posted if you scroll down to the bottom, the main.cpp file 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 Main engine;

 return 0;
}

Comment: Can you confirm for me that "Display: destroyed\n\n" is printed during execution? This sounds an awful lot like the destructor being invoked, but with your changes that should not be happening.

Comment: it isn't, it wasn't happening before i changed it to construct the other way either, i just have four initialize statements for input, renderingEngine, Display and physicsEngine. maybe i need to buy a c++11 book hahha